# Python list comprehension error, join sub list not working

Tags: python, string, sublist

Here is my REPL code:

```
>>> x = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "ef"]]

>>> [""join(i) for i in x]
```

Got

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [""join(i) for i in x]
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

While I tested each separate part, don't see which is invalid

Comment: `"".join`, not `""join`.

Comment: You're getting banned from ProgrammerHumor @Aplet123.

Answer (score 3):

```
["".join(i) for i in x]
```

You forgot the dot between the string and the join function